# UPDATE em outra tabela ao atualizar um registro não funciona - CODEIGNITER - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Olá, o código para fazer um update de um registro em outra tabela não funciona.
Preciso fazer um update da tabela `vendas` ao salvar um registro da tabela `lancamentos`.

na tabela `lancamentos` existe a coluna `vendas_id`, que contém o id relacionado a uma venda faturada.
Quando eu editar o lançamento, preciso que o `idLancamentos` passe para a coluna `lancamentos_id` na tabela `vendas`.

**O controller tem a seguinte função:**

```html
            if ($this->financeiro_model->edit('lancamentos',$data,'idLancamentos',$this->input->post('id')) == TRUE) {

                //$estornado = 0;
                $venda = $this->input->post('venda_id');
                $lancamento = $this->input->post('idLancamentos');

                $sql = "UPDATE vendas set lancamentos_id = lancamentos_id = ? WHERE idVendas = ?";
                $this->db->query($sql, array($lancamento, $venda));

                $this->atualizaSaldoEditar();
                echo json_encode(array('result'=> true));

                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','lançamento editado com sucesso!');
                redirect($urlAtual);
            } else {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Ocorreu um erro ao tentar editar lançamento!');
                echo json_encode(array('result'=> false));
                redirect($urlAtual);
            }
```

**Para ser mais preciso, acredito que o problema esteja no Código abaixo:**

```html
$venda = $this->input->post('venda_id');
$lancamento = $this->input->post('idLancamentos');

$sql = "UPDATE vendas set lancamentos_id = lancamentos_id = ? WHERE idVendas = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array($lancamento, $venda));
```

Comment: Cara, pra começar, não faz o menos sentido você te o uma `vendas_id` na tabela `lancamentos` e um `lancamentos_id` na tabela `vendas`. Segundo, está uma bagunça seus nomes de colunas, tem hora que você usa Camel Case, ten hora que não...não está claro o que é de verdade. Terceiro, qual erro você recebe, dá alguma mensagem ou simplesmente não atualiza?

Comment: Amigo, não leve a mal o CamelCase, pois coloquei uma rápida do que preciso.
O sentido de ter a venda em lançamentos está em...
Quando registro uma venda, ela ainda não pertence ao lançamento, mas quando eu FATURO esta venda, elá é incluída como Receita no lançamento, sendo que o valor do saldo faturado é agregado a uma conta.
Se lançamento = Receita = Saldo positivo | 
Se lançamento = Despesa = Saldo Negativo

Comment: Então, caso haja necessidade de estornar este lançamento.
Pago para Estornado, eu possa atribuir este mesmo status para o registro da venda em questão.
E para isso eu preciso atribuir o ID do lançamento para a tabela de vendas.

E não recebe erro nenhum.
Obtenho a mensagem que o registro foi salvo com sucesso e o status na tabela `lancamentos` esta sendo alterado,  porem o update na tabela vendas não é realizado.

Comment: Poste o conteúdo deste método: `$this->atualizaSaldoEditar();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro está neste update:

```
$sql = "UPDATE vendas set lancamentos_id = lancamentos_id = ? WHERE idVendas = ?";
```

Além de conter erro de sintaxe utilizando `x = x = x`, o seu `lancamentos_id` na querie é a coluna da sua própria tabela.

O correto seria simplesmente isso aqui:

```
$sql = "UPDATE vendas set lancamentos_id = ? WHERE idVendas = ?";
```

Comment: É, já tentei desta forma, mas não foi.

Comment: Mas dá algum erro?

Comment: Não dá erro, é como se não existisse a querie.

Comment: Gere a querie com os valores corretos e execute direto no banco para ver se funciona

Comment: Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`banco`.`vendas`, CONSTRAINT `fk_vendas_lancamentos1` FOREIGN KEY (`lancamentos_id`) REFERENCES `lancamentos` (`idLancamentos`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

UPDATE vendas set lancamentos_id = '50' WHERE idVendas = '1'

Comment: Mas deu certo.
Eu retirei a restrição de chave estrangeira na tabela vendas e apliquei a tua correção.

Obrigado

Comment: Opa, ia falar com relação a isso mesmo... que bom que deu certo!

Comment: Amigo, preciso lhe perguntar algo.
Sabe como fazer dois updates usando a sintexe `$sql = "UPDATE vendas set lancamentos_id = ? WHERE idVendas = ?";`?

Só para melhor entendimento, algo como:
``$sql = "UPDATE vendas set lancamentos_id = ? set faturado = ? WHERE idVendas = ?";``

Comment: Seria o caso de criar 2 updates ou existe possibilidade de se fazer num só?
Conforme documentação PHP, eu sei que existe possibilidade de fazer em apenas um, mas no codeigniter, muda um pouco.

Comment: É possível no `PHP` ou em qualquer `framework` executar um único método, mas na prática você terá que executar dois `UPDATE` no banco de dados.